# Principal minors of sum of a matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix such that all principal minors of $A$ are positive and $D$ be a diagonal matrix with non-negative diagonal entries. I need to prove that all the principal minors of $A+D$ are positive. 
Can anyone give any idea or hint to prove this?!

Comment: While it's a good idea, unfortunately the statement is not true. Consider $$\begin{pmatrix}-3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$ In this case, the first matrix has determinant $>0$, the diagonal matrix is non-negative, but the sum no longer has positive determinant. So unfortunately, this is not a "local" result as you hoped. The proof probably has to make use of the fact that all of the minors are positive.

Comment: And just to be clear, we're not limiting ourselves to Hermitian matrices right?

Comment: No. A is any square matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will make essential use of the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). The key result is the following proposition. I've included a full proof, so try not to read past the initial proposition if you want to try your hand at it yourself.

**Proposition**: Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that all principal minors are positive. Then the matrix
$$A + \lambda\mathbf{e}_k\mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T}_k$$ 
has positive determinant for all $\lambda \ge 0$.

Here $\mathbf{e}_k\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $k$th standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Proof**: This is a direct application of the matrix determinant lemma, which says that we have
$$\det(A + \lambda\mathbf{e}_k\mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T}_k) = \det(A) + \lambda[\mathrm{Adj}(A)]_{kk},$$
where $[\mathrm{Adj}(A)]_{kk}$ denotes the $kk$th entry of the adjugate matrix of $A$. Explicitly, we know that 
$$[\mathrm{Adj}(A)]_{kk} = C_{kk},$$
where $C_{kk}$ is the $kk$th cofactor of $A$. But this is a principal minor of $A$, which by assumption was positive. Therefore it follows that we have
$$\det(A + \lambda\mathbf{e}_k\mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T}_k) = \det(A) + \lambda[\mathrm{Adj}(A)]_{kk} \ge \det(A) > 0,$$
where the $\geq$ sign becomes an equality if and only if $\lambda = 0$. $\square$

**Corollary:** Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that all principal minors are positive. Then the matrix
$$B=A + \lambda\mathbf{e}_k\mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T}_k$$ 
also has all principal minors positive for $\lambda \ge 0$.

**Proof**: Consider a principal minor $[B]_I$, where $I$ is the index set of the rows/columns retained when forming the minor. If $k\notin I$, then the principal minor has not changed, i.e. we have $[B]_I = [A]_I > 0$. If $k\in I$, then apply the proposition to the underlying submatrix. $\square$

Finally, we can prove your result.

**Proposition**: Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with all positive principal minors. Let $D$ be a non-negative diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $d_k$. Then $A+D$ has all principal minors positive.

**Proof**: We can simply update $A$ one step at a time using the corollary. First, since $A$ has all principal minors positive, it follows that 
$$A_1 = A + d_1\mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_1^\mathrm{T}$$
also has all principal minors positive. Now apply the corollary again to
$$A_2 = A_1 + d_2\mathbf{e}_2\mathbf{e}_2^\mathrm{T},$$
and inductively, to
$$A_k = A_{k-1} + d_k\mathbf{e}_k\mathbf{e}_k^\mathrm{T},$$
and conclude that each $A_k$ has all positive principal minors. The desired result follows by noting that $A+D = A_n$. $\square$

Comment: I think in the proof of the proposition there is a small mistake.$det(A + \lambda \mathbf{e}_k\mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T}_k)$ = $det(A) + \alpha[\mathrm{Adj}(A)]_{kk}$ where $\alpha = \frac{\lambda }{\det(A)}\ge 0$.

Comment: @LaRias I don't think so. You can look at the statement of the matrix determinant lemma I linked to, it's just the adjugate.

Comment: Ya you are correct! I was looking at the first statement given in the link where the expression is in terms of $A^{-1}$ and missed to multiply it by $det(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be proved by mathematical induction on the sizes $n$ of the matrices. The base case is trivial. Suppose the statement is true for matrices of sizes up to $n-1$. Now consider matrices $A$ and $D$ of size $n$. By induction hypothesis, all *proper* principal minors of $A+D$ are positive. It remains to show that $\det(A+D)>0$.

Define $f(t)=\det(A+tD)$ for every $t\geq0$. By [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula),
$$
f'(t)=\operatorname{trace}\left(\operatorname{adj}(A+tD)D\right).
$$
Note that $\operatorname{adj}(A+tD)$ has a positive diagonal, because its diagonal elements are *proper* principal minors of $A+tD$, which are guaranteed to be positive by induction hypothesis. Therefore $f'(t)$ is always nonnegative. Yet, $f(0)=\det A$ is positive. So, $f$ must stay positive on $[0,\infty)$. In particular, $\det(A+D)=f(1)>0$.